# Creating a product gallery

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, laravel-8

I would like to display my gallery images as shown bellow,
[image: Expected output]

The image comes from a laravel controller as a collection and is chunked. So basically I know how to chunk the images and I guess that I should chunk the chunks further hen style appropriately this is where my problem is. How do I do that or what is the best approach and is there anyone who can show me how or where can I learn to do this.

So  far I have tried the chunking a bootstrap grid system but that is only producing rows and columns based on the number of images.
Here is my attempt using chunk plus bootstrap

```
    @foreach ($images->chunk(4) as $key=>$image)
        <div class="row">
            @foreach ($image as $item)
            @if ($key===0)
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div>
                    <span class="image-block block2">
                    <a class="image-zoom" href="{{ asset('uploads/property/large/'.$item->path) }}" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]">                         
                            <img src="{{ asset('uploads/property/small/'.$item->path) }}" class="img-responsive" alt="CEC Gallery"></a>
                </span>
                </div>
            </div>                        
            @else
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <span class="image-block block2">
                    <a class="image-zoom" href="{{ asset('uploads/property/large/'.$item->path) }}" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]">                         
                            <img src="{{ asset('uploads/property/small/'.$item->path) }}" class="img-responsive" alt="CEC Gallery"></a>
                </span>
                </div>
            </div>
                
            @endif
            @endforeach
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use CSS [Flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) to achieve this.

You could iterate through your images like so:

```
<div class="gallery">
    @foreach ($image as $item)
    <div class="gallery__item">
        <a class="image-zoom" href="{{ asset('uploads/property/large/'.$item->path) }}" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]">
            <img src="{{ asset('uploads/property/small/'.$item->path) }}" class="img-responsive" alt="CEC Gallery">
        </a>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

```css
.gallery {
    display: flex;
    align-items: start;
    justify-content: left;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.gallery__item {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 50%;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    min-height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery__item">1</div>
  <div class="gallery__item">2</div>
  <div class="gallery__item">3</div>
</div>
```

**Assumptions**:

1. No gutter between images.

Comment: OK and any idea how to show the remaining images in the list (the ones under other)

Comment: So basically what you want is to show a couple of images(first chunk) and the rest as a single tile called other. Correct?

Comment: You are right, that is exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

```css
.gallery {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: start;
    justify-content: left;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gallery__item {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 24%;
    flex-basis: 24%;
    max-width: 24%;
    min-height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 400px;
    margin: 2px;
}

#remain {
    width: 24%;
    max-width: 24%;
    min-height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 400px;
    background-size: cover;
    animation-name: switch;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: normal;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

@keyframes switch {
    0% {
        background: url(/1234567.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }

    25% {
        background: url(/1234567.jpeg);
        background-size: cover;
    }

    50% {
        background: url(/autoimages/background2.jpeg);
        background-size: cover;
    }

    100% {
        background: url(/1234567.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
     <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery__item">1</div>
        <div class="gallery__item">2</div>
        <div class="gallery__item">3</div>
        <div class="gallery__item">4</div>
        <div class="gallery__item">5</div>
        <div class="gallery__item">6</div>
        <div class="gallery__item">7</div>
        <div class="gallery__item" id="remain">8+
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: @clifstats basically what I'm asking is how I can display 1,2,3,4 in the first row then in the second row show 5,6,7 and 8910 stacked together showing the count just as in the image